# How to bypass the module not found on react.js

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am stuck at the expo page. When I load the landing page, I get an error. .. "Module not found. " quick google search said i need to remove package-lock.json and reinstall npm back gain. I tried that method and i still run into the same problem. What should I do?

```
    Failed to compile C:/Users/Asus/instragram/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve './components/auth/Landing' in 'C:\Users\Asus\instragram'
```

Below is the code of the landing page:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, View , Button} from 'react-native'
    export default function Landing;({navigation}) {
        return (
            <view style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <button>
                    title="Register"
                    onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("Registr")}
                </button>
                <button>
                    title="Login"
                    onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
                </button>
    
            </view>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Don't put code / error messages in images, put them in the text of the question

Comment: Is that better? Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks though

Comment: is your path `./components/auth/Landing` having default export?

Comment: Please attach the code of Landing page too

Comment: I have added the landing page too

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing ; in line 3 of Landing page :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View , Button} from 'react-native';

export default function Landing({navigation}) {
        return (
            <view style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <button>
                    title="Register"
                    onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("Registr")}
                </button>
                <button>
                    title="Login"
                    onPress = {() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
                </button>
    
            </view>
        )
    }
```